# How to convert extracted value from datetime to char in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need convert to char the extracted year from datetime to char in Oracle PL/SQL. How can I reach this?
The code gives me `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments tips 'TO_CHAR'`

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PrintCustomersKPI IS
  v_average_duration NUMBER;
  v_tab CHAR := chr(9);
BEGIN
   FOR v_year IN (SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(year FROM purchaseday) as PurchaseYear FROM Purchase ORDER BY PurchaseYear DESC)
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('YEAR: ' || TO_CHAR(v_year, 'yyyy'));
    END LOOP;
END;
EXEC PrintCustomersKPI;
```

Comment: Use `v_year.PurchaseYear`.  `v_year` is the name of the record that is created to hold the results of the implicit cursor.  You have to specify which element of the record you want to access.

Comment: Oh, thanks... and what parameter should i add to to_char function ?Now It gives me error: `01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model"`

Comment: `PurchaseYear` is a number so no second parameter is likely necessary (unless you want to do something like include a thousands separator which would be really unusual).  Or remove the `extract` call in your query, return a `date`, and use the `yyyy` format model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just

```
TO_CHAR(v_year.PurchaseYear)
```

Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in the below way as well. You have to use the Alias column while printing the result

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PrintCustomersKPI IS
  v_average_duration NUMBER;
  v_tab CHAR := chr(9);
BEGIN
   FOR v_year IN (SELECT DISTINCT  TO_CHAR(purchaseday, 'YYYY') as PurchaseYear FROM Purchase ORDER BY PurchaseYear DESC)
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('YEAR: ' || v_year.PurchaseYear  );
    END LOOP;
END;
EXEC PrintCustomersKPI;
```